# Taylor coefficients and termwise integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Many special function are calculated using its Taylor series, and is an efficient method of estimation the values of a function. Nevertheless, for some function evaluation of a formula of Taylor coefficients might be difficult.
I would like to ask if it is possible to compute integrals of compositions of elementary analytic functions $f(h(g))$ following ways:

1. Using values of the inner functions as $x$ and decompose over outer function as
   $$f(h(g(x))) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(h(g(x))-a)^n$$ and then integrate termwise.

or

2. Using series composition as in the [article](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/%7Ebrent/pub/pub045.html) and then again integrate termwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example, $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, $\displaystyle h(y)=\frac{y}{-2}$, and $\displaystyle g(x)=y=x^2$.
Taking $f'$ as simple derivative of outer function $\displaystyle \frac{df}{dz}=\frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$
what is also $f''=f'''$ and so on (the $e$ function, *youknowit*).

Taking your suggested formula **1.** at $a=0$ will result $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left (-x^2/2\right )^n}{n!}$ what is nicely **wrong**.

In contrast, for $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ the first few derivatives are
$\displaystyle f'=\frac{-x\cdot e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$,
$\displaystyle f''=\frac{(x^2-1)\cdot e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$,
$\displaystyle f'''=\frac{x\left(-x^2+3\right)\cdot e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$,
$\displaystyle f^{(4)}=\frac{(x^4-6x^2+3)\cdot e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$,
thus its Taylor series is

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\left (1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{x^6}{48}+\frac{x^8}{384}\mathrm{...}\right )$.
I know, it's not a generally valid explanation. Nonetheless this example shows clearly, your option **1.** is invalid.